# Не запускается Django проект

Tags: django, python-3.x

Ошибка:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Подскажите если кто сталкивался что можно с этим сделать как исправить?

Вот часть кода `settings.py`

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See 
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'rt5po3bmwqav^cpc*55rnzbyy!+86)+k6polz-bc_m4vr0plxu'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'landing',
    'article',
]
```

Если это как то поможет

Используется `PyCharm`

Comment: Как запускаете? `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` прописан где надо?

Comment: а где должен быть прописан? запускаю как обычно в pycharm кнопкой run  но если через командную строку запускать то тоже самое происходит

Comment: Или в переменной окружения, или в скрипте через который запускаете (в `manage.py` прописано автоматически), вообще про это есть в [документации](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/settings.html#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)